# i want to return a values from database in laravel using mysql where command

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

i want to return a values from database in laravel using mysql where command but it gives empty result

this code gives result but i could not want this way

```
$data = admin::all();
            foreach ($data as $dat) {
                echo $dat->name;
                echo $dat->email;
            }
```

i want to do it like this but this give empty result

```
$data = admin::where('username', '=', $uname);
            foreach ($data as $dat) {
                echo $dat->name;
                echo $dat->email;
            }
```

Comment: have you tried running the statement in a standalone database client to be sure you have a record with `username` that matches `$uname`?

Answer (score 3):

The `where()` only builds the query for you. You still need to retrieve the results somehow. The way to do that is the `get()` method. Like this:

```
$data = admin::where('username', '=', $uname)->get();
```